# jQuery onclick to change class name of an element

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I have a div with a background image and for example, its class is image1.

I have 3 icons, on page load image1 is on the screen. When my 2nd icon is clicked, I want the class of the div to change to image2 which will therefore show a different background image, and if the 3rd icon is clicked, it will change to image 3.

I can use remove/add class in jQuery to remove "image1" for example but it could be on image2 etc.. so would I tell it to remove "image1" AND "image2" and add "image3", and what would happen in that case because only 1 of the 2 classes i'd be telling it to remove are actually there, would it cause an error?

Is this the right thing to do?

```
<div id="fullbg" class="image1></div>
<a class="img1link" href="#">show image 1</a>
<a class="img2link" href="#">show image 2</a>
<a class="img3link" href="#">show image 3</a>

$('.img1link').click(function() {
    $(#fullbg).removeClass('image2 image3');
    $(#fullbg).addClass('image1');
});

$('.img2link').click(function() {
    $(#fullbg).removeClass('image1 image3');
    $(#fullbg).addClass('image2');
});

$('.img3link').click(function() {
    $(#fullbg).removeClass('image1 image2');
    $(#fullbg).addClass('image3');
});
```

Comment: You just forgot to add `quotes`. `$(#fullbg)` should be `$('#fullbg')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use only one class there, much better is to do:

```
$(#fullbg).attr('class', 'image3');
```

Comment: This precludes using any other classes on the object for other purposes like CSS formatting.  I would not say this is "much" better.

Comment: He does not use any other classes in example, so it is faster, less code is executed and therefor "much" better.

Comment: And, a lot less flexible and more brittle because if some front-end engineer decides to add a class to help with CSS formatting, things break.  Performance is NOT an issue at all here in a `.click()` type function.  Architecturally precluding the use of other classes for formatting reasons is NOT a recommended solution.

Comment: Is attr instead of addClass? Sorry, i'm a novice with jQuery.

Comment: Just to clarify, the #fullbg div with the changing classes is just a wrapper div with varying background images depending on what icon is clicked so there wont be any need for a class to be used for any other CSS formatting.

Comment: Thanks Adrian (and it also has an ID), think jfriend00 can mark it now as a useful answer.

Comment: @Adrian - When there are other ways to do things without this compromise, I don't think it's good to code in "hidden" limitations (not immediately apparent to others on the project) that make it so you can't use other classes on any object.  Why code such a limitation when you don't need to?  It's your choice if you want to, but I wouldn't.

Comment: OK I have this but it doesnt seem to be working:
`$(document).ready(function() {
$('.img1link').click(function() {
 $(#contactpage).attr('class', 'image3');
});

$('.img2link').click(function() {
 $(#contactpage).attr('class', 'image3');
});

$('.img3link').click(function() {
 $(#contactpage).attr('class', 'image3');
});
});`

#contactpage is the div that i want the class going to and .link1img is the anchor to be clicked.

Comment: and its supposed to be image 1, image2 and image 3, ignore the fact that every line says image3, just an oversight.

Comment: it's OK, got it, needed to wrap #contact page in '#contactpage' and also instead of `$(document).ready(function() {` i have used `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {`

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to list a bunch of classes to remove.  It will just remove the ones that are present and not cause any errors.  That is an acceptable way to do what you're trying to do.

FYI, this is a place where chaining simplifies your code a bit too:

```
$("#fullbg").removeClass('image2 image3').addClass('image1');
```

---

Since you have a lot of copied code in your current implementation, it's probably better the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) up the whole implementation with just one common event handler:

```
$("#fullbg a").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).index() + 1;
    $("#fullbg").removeClass('image1 image2 image3').addClass('image' + num);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any classes for styling purpose you can use the function *.removeClass()* without parameter. In that case all classes are removed, you don't have to pass all possible classes that should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to `removeClass`. Here is a generic working example with any number of images.

```
$("#fullbg").removeClass( function() { 
    classNames = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        classNames += "image" + (i+1) + " ";
    }
    return classNames;
}).addClass("image1");
```

The inner function creates the string `image1 image2 image3 ...` to remove them.